# Unable to format json data dynamically

Tags: java, json

I Need to dynamically form the target json from given below input Json. Please let me know how can i do the same using java because as per my knowledge the below output json structure is not valid (Standard is not followed) but still i need to have the structure like this only (Target side wants to call the api like below output json format only).

Input Json:

```
{
"MOCType":"Temporary Repair","MOCStatusUpdatedDateTime":"2018-10-31T10:00:00Z","TagNumber":"4850-A-101-A01A,4850-A-101-A03C,4850-A-101-A08,4850-A-101-A10A,4850-A-101-A10B,4850-A-101-A10C,4850-A-101-A11,4850-A-101-A12,6320-T-003C","Id":"CLX000A"
}
```

Output Json:

```
{
"4850-A-101-A01A" :{
"Temporary Repair (eMOC)": "OK"
},

"4850-A-101-A03C" :{
"Temporary Repair (eMOC)": "OK"
},

"4850-A-101-A08" :{
"Temporary Repair (eMOC)": "OK"
},

"4850-A-101-A10B" :{
"Temporary Repair (eMOC)": "OK"
}
}
```

Comment: seems to be valid json.  You can check at jsonlint.com

Comment: The main "problem" is probably that the input JSON contains a `String` as value of `"TagNumber"` that needs to be interpreted as a list - you need to parse/split that yourself, because it is not a JSON array.

Comment: Hi Hulk, Yes, I am doing the spliting of the tagNumber and when i am trying to create the document structure using JsonArrayBuilder kvArrBld = Json.createArrayBuilder(); object then it is formatting like below:{"4850-A-101-A01A":[{"Temporary Repair (eMOC)":"OK"}]} but i need to create it dynamically so that i can expected Target Json. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String str="4850-A-101-A01A,4850-A-101-A03C,4850-A-101-A08,4850-A-101-A10A,4850-A-101-A10B,4850-A-101-A10C,4850-A-101-A11,4850-A-101-A12,6320-T-003C";

ArrayList aList= new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(str.split(",")));
  for(int i=0;i<aList.size();i++)
  {      
      String tagNumber=(String) aList.get(i);
      JsonData jsonData = new JsonData();

      jsonData.addNode(new Node((String) aList.get(i), new TestObject(emocStatus)));          
      String OuptputDoc1=jsonData.toJSONStirng().replaceAll("Temporary_Repair","Temporary Repair (eMOC)" ); 
      System.out.println(OuptputDoc1);
  }
```

}

Comment: Output from above code:    {"4850-A-101-A01A":{"Temporary Repair (eMOC)":"OK"}}
{"4850-A-101-A03C":{"Temporary Repair (eMOC)":"OK"}}
{"4850-A-101-A08":{"Temporary Repair (eMOC)":"OK"}}
{"4850-A-101-A10A":{"Temporary Repair (eMOC)":"OK"}}                                                                       But i need to get a JsonArray instead of the JsonString of each TagNumber. Please help